# Autofac passing paramter to construtor

Tags: .net, autofac

Ok, I have written and re-written this question many times.... But basically my question is simple: How do i pass a value into a constructor if I am using Autofac in either C# or VB (.net)?

I have done many searches and read a lot of ways, but nothing seems to be what i am looking for.

I have a userClass that takes a userID in the constructor, I need to be able to pass the userID value into the constructor at runtime (as and when i have a userID, example, a visitor opens a userDetails page that has a userID, i need to instantiate the class passing in the userID so i have a user object with all the details)

All documentation seems to be only using dependencies that require no parameters... Is it bad practice to do it this way now? Is it better to have no parameters
In a constructor for Autofac then maybe have a method that initiates the object data (user data)?

any other answers seem to add the parameters within the global.asax applicataion_Start, which is no good either, as i need to add at runtime, and other answers suggest building the container again... So will build all the unrelated dependencies for other classes just to pass one parameter to one class? (and would mean, i need to access the global.asax public property from within my library project??

Can anyone help let me know how to do this (don't need full code, just brief description about location of code and what it should do), or an alternative if passing parameters is now bad practice

Comment: Did you see the documentation - https://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced/delegate-factories.html?

Comment: You know, autofac is about Dependency Injection. I have never heard that somebody uses autofac that way. If you need currentUserId, you can find it via Principle object. UserId is int or guid? Autofac (Dependency Injection) injects services or repositories. Autofac (Dependency Injection) doesn't inject primitive types or types like that.